# How to modify eg-01-php-jwt php project?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to use example project eg-01-php-jwt for JWT to grant an access token to service integrations. it is published here: https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-php-jwt

Currently email addresses and signer names of the recipients are stored in the ds_config.ini file.

I want to keep them in the separate file called "parameters.php" where I define path to documents that should be signed as well.

I include this file into send_envelope.php with the include_once('parameters.php') statement.

How to modify all files (means: ds_config.php, and send_envelope.php) in this project in order to make it workable.

Thanks

Comment: are you asking how to modify it so that instead of using ds_config.ini, information will come from parameters.php? if so - can you share the code of parameteres.php?

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps are that you download the source from the GitHub repository to your own development machine.

Then change the source as you wish. At this point it is your source on your computer, you can do anything.

You won't be able to upload your changes to the DocuSign github repository but you can (and should) backup your source to another computer or service.

Your question implies that you are new to PHP, I suggest that a PHP course (online or in person) would be of great help to you.